# How to move a function down(up) in a class in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to move a function down to group similar function together in PyCharm, But I can't seem to find a good way to do it. What I hope is when cursor is on foo1, I can press a shortcut to move down foo1 or I can drag the function down with mouse when I press Alt(for example).

Example when press a shortcut when cursor is on foo1

From

```
class Foo:
    def foo1(self):
        pass
    def foo2(self):
        pass
```

To

```
class Foo:
    def foo2(self):
        pass
    def foo1(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, what you can do is highlight the text that you want to move down and on mac use `Command + Shift + Down Arrow` to move a block of code downward.  On Windows the command is `Alt + Shift + Down Arrow`.  [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/adding-deleting-and-moving-code-elements.html#d943836e103) is the pycharm reference for this shortcut.

Answer (score -3):

Visit this site

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/move-refactorings.html

It guides you with the step by step procedure.